# Closing the window delays if a mouse hook is set

Tags: winapi, mouse-hook

If I set a low level mouse hook, `WH_MOUSE_LL`,
when I click the **[x]** (Close) button the window delays ~500ms and then it disappears.

Do you know what causes the delay?  And, is there a way to fix it?

(the window and the hook are created with direct calls to win32 api in C++)

Answer (score 1):

WH_MOUSE_LL is a different kind of hook from most other ones.  It is implemented by calling the hook procedure directly rather than injecting a DLL.  That requires a message loop to be actively pumping.  The odds that there isn't one anymore after you close a window are high.  Be sure to unhook in the WM_CLOSE message handler.

Comment: @nobugz, I've tried your solution, and other combinations, but it didn't work. It's a normal (main) window with a message loop. With `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` I don't have that problem.

Comment: I can't guess what the problem might be without seeing repro code.  Post it to a file sharing service somewhere.

Comment: No repro, it instantly closes.  This suggests the problem is external.

Comment: ok, thanks for helping. Did you try it on Windows XP or on newer version?