# C# Win32 Mousehook causing slow and unresponsiveness

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a mouse capture class i found that is as follows

```
public static class MouseHelper
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private static LowLevelMouseProc process = HookCallback;

    private static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    private static IntPtr Hook(LowLevelMouseProc process)
    {
        using (Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule currentModule = currentProcess.MainModule)
        {
            
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, process, GetModuleHandle(currentModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0)
            Console.Write(((MouseMessages)wParam).ToString());
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        hookId = Hook(process);
    }

    public static void UnHook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
    }
}
```

You run it with `MouseHelper.Start()`. Problem is when i do, the mouse gets slow and unresponsive and im trying to make the program run fine without that happening

I don know what to do about it i thought maybe threads could be used but i couldnt figure out how to use them, and im NOT allowed to use winforms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing the window delays if a mouse hook is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005741/closing-the-window-delays-if-a-mouse-hook-is-set)

Comment: @RaymondChen possibly i dont understand the answer

Comment: The main issue will be that WH_MOUSE_LL is attempting to capture events across processes which means that Windows will switch to the hook process and back for every event. Since your hook is running on your main UI thread, this is going to be affected as Windows is told to synchronize it across processes/threads. It's not quite as simple as just moving the handler to a background thread as the hook expects to run in the same thread as where SetWindowsHookEx was called. Capturing low level events should also aim to process extremely fast, so no UI-synchronized `Console` calls.

Comment: Did you call `Start()` from a thread that pumps messages? `WH_MOUSE_LL` requires that the installing thread pump messages.

Comment: In addition, [LowLevelMouseProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelmouseproc) says *the `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook is not injected into another process. Instead, the context switches back to the process that installed the hook and it is called in its original context. Then the context switches back to the application that generated the event* as @StevePy said. Maybe the global `WH_MOUSE` is a workaround. It's also worth to note that *Global hooks should be restricted to special-purpose applications or to use as a development aid during application debugging.*

Comment: @StevePy its to be able to convert the mouse x and y on the screen into the consoles character grid, i need the console calls or some way to write to console

Comment: @RaymondChen i havent tried that ill try that

Comment: I'd consider writing the output to a `volatile` `string`, or better, just a pair of `int`/`long` that the UI thread can poll such as using a timer every second or so to update the console with the relevant value at the time. The main point will be if you want to hook into low level events you do not want to be marshalling back to the UI thread of a process, and since this event will fire extremely frequently you will want to ensure any operation performed is extremely light to avoid introducing stutter.

Comment: @StevePy could you provide any code? ive spent a while trying to do what youve described but i cant get it to work